# Including Jquery in smarty

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I use Smarty v.1.6

I make `select` form in tpl with onchange.

Here is my code snippet :

```
<div class="row">
    <select name="group" id="group">
    {foreach from=$userGroupsData item=group}
        <option value="{$group.id}">{$group.name}</option>
    {/foreach}
    </select>
</div>
<div id="fetchmember">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> <!-- is it right? -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    {literal}                   
    $('#group').on('change',function(){
    alert("hello");                     
    });
    {/literal}                      
</script>
</div>
```

I just want to make sure that the jquery working fine, so i test it with `alert`. But the alert cannot appear. Is there something wrong with my code? Please help.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your jQuery code inside `$(function(){ //your code here });` to execute it when the DOM is ready. See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(function(){ 
  $('#group').on('change',function(){
    alert("hello");                     
  });
});
```

Try loading jQuery from a CDN like so `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`.

And you don't really need the `{literal}` block here. Simply use a space or a line break after opening curly braces in your JS code so smarty doesn't think it's a function.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but the alert still not appear. Where i have to put <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> ?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put it. Generally I would prefer the `<head>` section of your html file. Do you have the jquery.js file inside the same folder as your html file?

Comment: And this will be your problem. Try putting the jquery.js file in the same folder as your php script that uses the template. Or just try loading jQuery from a CDN like so `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`